# Combining common API for similar but different data structures in C

Tags: c, structure

I have two structures: **A** containing **a,b,c,d** as members and **B** containing **b,c,d** as members. I have multiple APIs that can be be passed either **A** or **B**.

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
} A;

typedef struct {
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
} B;

Set_b(struct A, int);
Set_c(struct A, int);
Set_d(struct A, int);

Set_b'(struct B, int);
Set_c'(struct B, int);
Set_d'(struct B, int);
```

What will be the easiest method to achieve common APIs for the same in C. E.g.

```
Set_b(X, int);
Set_c(X, int);
Set_d(X, int);
```

I’m not allowed to use a `union` as the code must conform to MISRA C.

Comment: Instead of describing your code, please *show* it. Try to create a [mcve] that you can show us. Also tell us what you have tried, how it worked or didn't work. And of course, please re-read [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: pass a union of the two structs

Comment: Are you trying to emulate inheritance in C?

Comment: @Anders Unions are not allowed as per MISRA C.

Comment: @SergeyA I want to have common APIs to avoid duplication of 1000 lines of code

Comment: Look for inspiration into what [GTK](http://gtk.org/) is doing, notably with its [GObject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/index.html)s; it probably is not MISRA C compliant, but it could give you some ideas. Are you allowed to use *generated* C code?

Comment: My impression from the MISRA C guidelines is that what you are wanting to do is not compatible with the guidelines. The purpose of the guidelines is to specify how to write C source code that will probably have fewer defects and be easier to test and to debug. Not sure that what you are wanting to do meets those goals. Your examples seem a bit contrived as I would expect some kind of an indication as to which struct with some kind of a struct id in the layout, usually the first member of the struct.

Comment: This question is really too abstract and broad to provide a specific approach. You need to add more details about the two different types of structs, the APIs, and what makes the APIs similar and different. How the functionality that deals with each of the struct types can be allocated to different source code functions or blocks will be governed by the various similarities and differences as well as the dependencies between the various pieces of functionality and the structs themselves.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want. Are you say that `struct B` is a subset of `struct A`? Or `set_b` only works with the `b` field of any structs?

Comment: @Amadeus Struct B is a subset but offsets of its members are different

Comment: @RogMatthews if `set_b` only works on a specific field, decompose it. `void set_b(int, int);`, for example, and calls `set_b(A.b, 0);`

Answer (score 2):

C11 supports type-generic expressions, which should do what you're looking for:

```
#define Set_b(X, y) _Generic((X), A: Set_b_A,\
                                  B: Set_b_B \
                            )((X), (y))
```

Then just implement `Set_b_A` and `Set_b_B` for the appropriate types.

Comment: It is a perfect way to make your code undebuggable  and error prone.

Comment: That's a bit use-case dependent, but maybe, yeah.

Comment: @CarlNorum Really appreciate you reply but I don't think this will be appropriate for this specific use case as I have around 1000 Lines of code with 30+ APIs. Debugging will be tough :(

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way. It is debuggable and does not generate too much code (memcpy will be optimized out from the  actual code on any level of optimization) https://godbolt.org/z/lMShik

BTW in this case IMO the unsafe version is same safe as IMO it does break the strict aliasing rules.

```
typedef enum
{
    TYPE_A,
    TYPE_B,
    TYPE_C
}Types;


struct a 
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;    
};

struct b 
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

struct c 
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

void inline __attribute__((always_inline)) Set_a(void *ptr, Types type, int value)
{
    struct a a;
    struct b b;
    struct c c;

    switch(type)
    {
        case TYPE_A:
            memcpy(&a, ptr, sizeof(a));
            a.a = value;
            memcpy(ptr, &a, sizeof(a));
            break;
        case TYPE_B:
            memcpy(&b, ptr, sizeof(b));
            b.a = value;
            memcpy(ptr, &b, sizeof(b));
            break;
        case TYPE_C:
            memcpy(&c, ptr, sizeof(c));
            c.a = value;
            memcpy(ptr, &c, sizeof(c));
            break;
    }
}


void inline __attribute__((always_inline)) Set_a_unsafe(void *ptr, Types type, int value)
{
    struct a a;
    struct b b;
    struct c c;

    switch(type)
    {
        case TYPE_A:
            ((struct a *)ptr) -> a = value;
            break;
        case TYPE_B:
            ((struct b *)ptr) -> a = value;
            break;
        case TYPE_C:
            ((struct c *)ptr) -> a = value;
            break;
    }
}

    struct a x,y;


int main()
{
    Set_a(&x, TYPE_A, 45);
    Set_a_unsafe(&y, TYPE_B, 100);

    printf("%d\n", x.a);
    printf("%d\n", y.a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an interface. For example,

```
struct A {};                          // As you have defined                                                               
void set_b_for_A(struct A, int) {}    // function that works with A                                          

// interface                                                                          
struct helper {                                                                 
    void *ptr;                        // pointer to your structs variants (A, ...)                                                         
    void (*set_b)(struct helper *, int);   // helper to dispatch to correct worker                                          
};                                                                              


void set_b_helper_for_A(struct helper *pointer, int i) {   // helper for worker A                            
    struct A *s = (struct A *) pointer->ptr;                                    
    set_b_for_A(*s, i);                                                         
} 

struct helper helper_A {/* A struct */, set_b_helper_for_A};
```

Now your API

```
void set_b(struct helper *ptr, int i) {
     ptr->set_b(ptr, i);
}
```

and you call, for example:

```
set_b(&helper_A, 0);
```

Do the same for others structs

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different alternative approaches that could be used however it depends on what you own and can determine versus what you do not own and can not modify or change. The actual implementation may depend on how often `structA` is used with the API versus `structB`. You really do not provide sufficient information for a definitive suggested approach.

It appears that your posting can be restated as follows.

There are two structs, `structA` and `structB` which have members in common. These common members store the same type of data and on inspection the entirety of `structB` is contained in `structA` as in:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;      // beginning of portion that is same as structB below.
    int c;
    int d;      // end of portion that is same as structB below.
    int e;
} structA;

typedef struct {
    int b;       // same type of data as in b member of structA above
    int c;       // same type of data as in c member of structA above
    int d;       // same type of data as in d member of structA above
} structB;
```

For a concrete example, `structA` describes an object in some 3D space whose location is an x,y,z tuple which is specified in the `structA` members `b`, `c`, and `d` and `structB` is used to store a location only as an x,y,z tuple.

You have an API that works with the data in `structB` and since the same data is in `structA` you are faced with the problem that you have to have an API composed of a set of functions that is duplicated, one version of the API that takes as an argument `structB` and the other takes as an argument `structA`.

To extend our concrete example of the objects in 3D space, you have an API that contains a function `translate()` which translates coordinates by some distance. Because you have the two different structs according to MISRA C you will need to have two different versions of this function, `translate_structA()` which takes as an argument a `structA` and a second one `translate_structB()` which takes as an argument a `structB`.

So you are faced with have to write two versions of each function in your API and you do not want to do that.

**Alternative 1 - replace cloned members with actual struct**

Use good software engineering and rather than having this `structB` data type in the `structA` as a cloned set of members, instead replace those cloned members with a `structB`.

```
typedef struct {
    int b;       // same type of data as in b member of structA above
    int c;       // same type of data as in c member of structA above
    int d;       // same type of data as in d member of structA above
} structB;

typedef struct {
    int a;
    structB xyz;    // replace the cloned members with an actual structB
    int e;
} structA;
```

Then you write the API that works with a `structB` only in terms of `structB`. In those places where you are using a `structA`, you would just use the `xyz` member in the function call interface.

The nice thing about this approach is that should additional, new data types be added that require a `structB`, you just plop in the `structB` member rather than clone the members and the API using the `structB` can be used with the new data types.

However in order to take this approach you will need to own the technology and be able to make this kind of change. On the other hand this is the most straightforward and simplest and most readable alternative I can think of. It should also have quite good run time efficiency as well.

**A Note About the Next Two Alternatives**

Before I go into the next two alternatives, you should consider the basic flaw in both of these.

If the dependency of `structA` on `structB` is not specified as a kind of contract by using `structB` within `structA`, you introduce a kind of logical or cognitive [intermodule coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) in which you have a common component which is source code itself rather than a software component derived from source code.

Maintenance becomes a hassle because now the two structs must be changed together. And unless the linkage between the two areas is documented in the source code and the struct definitions themselves, a programmer new to the code will probably miss this.

And if new data types that use the `structB` data are introduced, the cloning step needs to be done again and you are just expanding the surface of complex linkages.

**Alternative 2 - marshalling to/from an interface object**

If you do not have control over the structs then another alternative is to perform marshalling of data to and from `structA` into a `structB` and then write the API in terms of `structB` only. Then any place where a `structA` needs to use the API, you would have a marshalling or transformation in which the particular data in `structA` is picked out to create a temporary `structB` which is then used with the function. If the function modifies the data in `structB` then you will need to copy the data from the `structB` back into the `structA` before eliminating the temporary.

**Alternatively** you could decide to do the API in terms of `structA` with marshalling in those cases where you want to use a `structB` with the API. This alternative may be preferable if most of the API uses `structA` with only a few using `structB`.

There are a couple of ways to do this approach of marshalling mainly determined by whether the API interfaces will return a changed data object or not.

The first is to have a duplicate set of functions which are called using a `structA` and this duplicate set of functions handles the marshaling of data between a temporary `structB` which is then used in a call to the actual API which takes a `structB`.

So something like:

```
int funcThing (structB thing);

int funcThing_structA (structA thing) {
    structB temp = {0};
    temp.b = thing.b;
    temp.c = thing.c;
    temp.d = thing.d;
    return funcThing (temp);
}
```

An alternative to the above would be something like:

```
int funcThing1 (structB thing);
int funcThing2 (structB thing);
int funcThing3 (structB thing);

int funcThingSet_structA (structA thing, int (*f)(structB thing)) {
    structB temp = {0};
    temp.b = thing.b;
    temp.c = thing.c;
    temp.d = thing.d;
    return f (temp);
}

// and the above is used like
structA thingA;
//  …  code
i = funcThingSet_structA (thingA, funcThing1);  // call funcThing1() with the structA data
i = funcThingSet_structA (thingA, funcThing2);  // call funcThing2() with the structA data

i = funcThingSet_structA (thingA, funcThing3);  // call funcThing3() with the structA data
```

If the functions may change the data then you will need to make sure that `structA` is updated as in:

```
int funcThing1 (structB *thing);
int funcThing2 (structB *thing);
int funcThing3 (structB *thing);

int funcThingSet_structA (structA *thing, int (*f)(structB *thing)) {
    structB temp = {0};
    int iRetVal = 0;

    temp.b = thing->b;
    temp.c = thing->c;
    temp.d = thing->d;

    iRetVal = f (&temp);

    thing->b = temp.b;
    thing->c = temp.c;
    thing->d = temp.d;
    return iRetVal;
}

// and the above is used like
structA thingA;
//  …  code
i = funcThingSet_structA (&thingA, funcThing1);  // call funcThing1() with the structA data
i = funcThingSet_structA (&thingA, funcThing2);  // call funcThing2() with the structA data

i = funcThingSet_structA (&thingA, funcThing3);  // call funcThing3() with the structA data
```

You may also have the API in terms of `structB` and use interface helper functions such as:

```
structB *AssignAtoB (structB *pB, structA A) {
    pB->b = A.b;
    pB->c = A.c;
    pB->d = A.d;
    return pB;
}

structB ConvertAtoB (structA A) {
    structB B = {0};
    B.b = A.b;
    B.c = A.c;
    B.d = A.d;
    return B;
}

void AssignBtoA (structA *pA, structB B) {
    pA->b = B.b;
    pA->c = B.c;
    pA->d = B.d;
}
```

Then you could do something like:

```
int funcThing1 (structB thing);
int funcThing2 (structB thing);
int funcThing3 (structB thing);


structA aThing;
//  …. code
{  // create a local scope for this temporary bThing.
    structB bThing = ConvertAtoB (aThing);
    i = funcThing1(bThing);
    // other operations on bThing and then finally.
    AssignBtoA (&aThing, bThing);
}
```

Or your API functions could return a `structB` in which case you could do something like:

```
structB funcThing1 (structB thing);
structB funcThing2 (structB thing);
structB funcThing3 (structB thing);

structA aThing;
//  …. code
{  // create a local scope for this temporary bThing.
    structB bThing = ConvertAtoB (aThing);
    bThing = funcThing1(bThing);
    bThing = funcThing2(bThing);
    AssignBtoA (&aThing, bThing);
}
```

or

```
{  // create a local scope for this temporary bThing.
    structB bThing = ConvertAtoB (aThing);
    AssignBtoA (&aThing, funcThing2(funcThing1(bThing)));
}
```

or even just

```
AssignBtoA (&aThing, funcThing2(funcThing1(ConvertAtoB (aThing))))
```

**Alternative 3 - use pointers in a fragile way**

Another alternative is create a pointer whose address starts with the `structB` portion of `structA`. While I am only vaguely familiar with MISRA, I have little doubt that this approach is against the rules since it is pretty much an abomination. However here it is anyway as I've seen it done in old code written by people without proper software engineering training.

With the above two structs, create a helper function or a macro that will generate a pointer to the offset in `structA` where the `structB` data begins. For instance:

```
structB MakeClone (structA thing) {
    return *(structB *)&thing.b;   // return a copy of the structB part of structA
}
```

or

```
structB *MakePointer (structA *pThing) {
    return (structB *)&thing.b;    // return a pointer to the structB part of structA
}
```

A Preprocessor macro may also be used to generate the pointer of the second case as in:

```
#define MAKEPOINTER(pThing) ((structB *)&((pThing)->b))
```

I have also seen where rather than using a helper function with an assignment as in:

```
int funcThing (structB *pBthing);

//  then in code want to use the above function with a structA
structA  aThing = {0};

// do things with aThing then call our function that wants a structB

funcThing (MAKEPOINTER(&aThing));
```

they will instead just hardcode the pointer as in which makes it really hard to find where this has been done during maintenance:

```
funcThing ((structB *)&(aThing.b));
```

I've also seen the pointer approach used with assignment using `memcpy()` to do the assignment. So if we have code like:

```
structA aThing = {0};
structB bThing = {0};

// somewhere in code we have
memcpy (&bThing, &aThing.b, sizeof(structB));  // assign the structB part of aThing to a structB
// more code to modify bThing then call our function
funcThing (&bThing);
memcpy (&aThing.b, &bThing, sizeof(structB));  // assign the structB back into the structB part of aThing
```

Using the pointer approach is fragile because if `structA` layout or `structB` layout should change things will probably break. The worse part is they could break with no indication as to why and the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it recommended to pass a pointer to a structure rather than full copy by value.

**Method 1:**
There is one method that is widely used in Linux kernel programming and that is `container_of` macro. If you give it a pointer to an element as input it will give you the structure containing that element. You can do something similar inside the functions `set_b()`, `set_c()`, `set_d()`.

**Method 2:**
Taking the example of `set_b()`, You can add 1 more extra argument to tell about the structure type and also make the first pointer a `void *`. The signature will become:

`set_b(void * str, int num, int str_type)`

You can use `str_type` as `1` for `struct A` and `0` for `struct B`. Now inside the function definition, you have to check for the type and recast the `void` pointer again to the proper `struct` type